# Sliding li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find a way to make `li` elements slides. I can make them all on one line (see my fiddle) and fit them in the `ul` width. But when I click on a NEXT button I want them slide to the right to show the hidden `li`.

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5cmR7/

Smiliar Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L5yEA/

*EDIT*: I want something like [this](http://jsbin.com/uduyiy) but built in a better way, and more precise when clicking NEXT.

Answer (score 3):

This is all you need:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/asiyus/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
var liN = $('ul.shop-groups li').length;
var galW = $('.content').width();    
var curr = 0; // Set current 'li' slide

function animate(){  
  var setCurr= (curr===-1) ? (curr = liN-1) : (curr = curr%liN);   
  $('ul.shop-groups').stop().animate({left: -(galW*curr) },1200);  
}

$('#prev, #next').click(function(){
  var who= (this.id==='next') ? curr++ : curr-- ;
  animate();
});
```

Just give an `ID` to your buttons:

```
<input id="prev" type="button" value="PREVIOUS"/>
<input id="next" type="button" value="NEXT"/>
```

And here is the changed CSS:

```
.content {
    position:relative; /**/
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    background-color:#555; 
    overflow:hidden; /**/
}

ul.shop-groups {
    position:absolute; /**/
    left:0px;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    width: 999999px;
}
ul.shop-groups a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
    min-width: 20px;
    padding: 2px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
li.shop-items {
    position:relative;/**/
    float:left;/**/
    border: solid 1px #d45;
    float : left;
    background-color:blue;
    height:248px;    /**/
    width:498px;     /**/
}
```

Comment: @JamWaffles Bad habit dear Jam, bad habit :) I'll reedit, thanks for mentioning. Should I also avoid the use of ternary operators?

Comment: Amen to good variable names! Bad variable names are nothing more than job security...

Comment: @naspinski :) Ok guys, i spit my coffee for the 2nd time. is now better? :)

Comment: Thanks, The thing is I need the elements to be like in my demo (next to each other). In fact, I want all the li to fit on 1 line. So when I click on NEXT, it would slide to show the next li. I don't want the li to be 100% of the DIV width, it needs to be like in my fiddle demo, but instead of having the li 9,10,11 and 12 to be on a second line, everything would be on 1 line, but only from 1 to 8 visible at first, and then when I click NEXT, it would slide to show from 1 to 9, and click again : 2 to 10, and so on. More like something like : http://jsbin.com/uduyiy ...but in a more precise way

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, is that what you mean?

http://jsfiddle.net/5cmR7/5/